# PyInstaller "ImportError: No module named Pyinstaller"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

This is the code that gets produced when I run python configure.py.

```
dan@Q430-Q530:~/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller$ python configure.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "configure.py", line 28, in <module>
    from PyInstaller import HOMEPATH, PLATFORM
ImportError: No module named PyInstaller
```

So, currently, I can't even get PyInstaller running because of a missing module called... PyInstaller. This is PyInstaller 2.0, and you can find some screens of the insides of the /pyinstaller-2.0 and the /pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller directories [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu6wc.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkd3H.png), respectively.

Does anyone here know what's going on? I tried copying the pyinstaller.py file in the /pyinstaller-2.0 directory into the /pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller directory, but I had no luck there.

This will probably turn out to be some ridiculously easy fix, but... It's got me stumped. If there's any more information needed, just ask and I shall try to provide.

Comment: Add pyInstaller to your Python Path

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With PyInstaller 2.0, you do not need to run configure or pyinstaller files. (Read PyInstaller 2.0 Document which comes with the installation files.)

To build your project; in the /your/path/to/pyinstaller/ directory, just run:

"python pyinstaller.py [opts] yourprogram.py"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `configure.py`, `makespec.py` and `build.py` files are supposed to be run directly in PyInstaller 2.0.

In the download there's a `pyinstaller.py` file in the top level - run that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `configure.py` is expecting `.` to be on your [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH). You should be able to run `python` in `/pyinstaller-2.0` and `import PyInstaller`. This should fail as it does in the script. You can add `.` to your environment variable in your `~/.bashrc` (make sure to source it or start a new terminal session to get the change). This would be something like:

```
export PYTHONPATH=.:$PYTHONPATH
```

Or, you can add to the top of the configure script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

Either way you should be able to run the script in `/pyinstaller-2.0` and import the `PyInstaller` module.

Comment: Whereabouts should "export PYTHONPATH=.:$PYTHONPATH" be placed in the .bashrc file?

Comment: it shouldn't matter as you usually append to whatever is in the variable before .. unless someone used bad form before and didn't end the statement with `:$PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in the bashrc file relating to python. Certainly, doing a search for "python" doesn't turn up anything. The import sys in configure.py option doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: yeah, it doesn't matter where in the `.bashrc` you put it.

Comment: Added it to the bottom: http://i.imgur.com/yyYyt.png Still not working. Maybe I'm doing it wrong... I seem to be completely clueless when it comes to setting environment variables in Linux. :p

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` cd into the `pyinstaller-2.0` dir and run configure from there?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZsaXD.png Still not happening. I might just leave it for a while and come back at it with a fresh mind. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.